# Creating a delay for .show

Tags: javascript

So I have this code to create a drop down for some tabs at the top of a webpage. I basically want a delay 900ms delay before it displays. I feel like I've done this before but I'm a complete noob when it comes to this kind of stuff.

```
    $("#header-links li a").hover(
        function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("data-target");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("z-index", "0");
        $(tab).css("z-index", "1").show();
}, function(){
     $('.tab-content').css("z-index", "0").hide();
     $(this).parent().removeClass("current");
}
);


});
```

Comment: Using `fadeIn(900)` may give the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `delay()`, but it only works on animations.

Passing a duration to `show()` makes it animated, any duration triggers it, so 1 millisecond should do the trick, even zero should work

```
$(tab).css("z-index", "1").delay(900).show(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use slide which will give perfect effect of dropdown menu

```
$("#header-links li a").hover(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("data-target");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("z-index", "0");
        $(tab).css("z-index", "1");
        $(tab).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
}, function(){
       $('.tab-content').css("z-index", "0")
       $('.tab-content').hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
       $(this).parent().removeClass("current");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `.delay(900)` just before `.show()`

So your code should be:

```
$(tab).css("z-index", "1").delay(900).show();
```

This stalls the drop down for 900ms.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a setTimeout to the function code you want to delay:

```
$("#header-links li a").hover(
     setTimeout(function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().addClass("current");
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
            var tab = $(this).attr("data-target");
            $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("z-index", "0");
            $(tab).css("z-index", "1").show();
    },900), function(){
         $('.tab-content').css("z-index", "0").hide();
         $(this).parent().removeClass("current");
    }
    );
    });
```